# for loop env with pattern,and output customed result

Tags: bash

my env is

```
service1=1
service2=a
service3=dd
......
servicen=xx
```

i search many resource,and try to write the file
test.text

```
$(
    services=$(compgen -A variable | grep service)
   echo $services | while read -r line ; do
        echo $line="$line" 
    done
    )
```

then i execute commid

```
eval "cat <<EOF
$(<test.text)
EOF
" | tee config.yaml 2> /dev/null
```

i think $services maybe array type,and echo $fname="$fname" should output

```
service1=1
service2=a
....
```

but the result is

```
service1 service2 service3=service1 service2 service3
```

how to get env server* prefix ,and for loop  output

```
server1=1
server2=a
....
```

what should i do that?thanks your any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still stuck, the problem you are having using the *command substitution* `services=$(compgen -A variable | grep service)` is that it creates one long string containing `service1 service2 service3...`. While you can parse that with normal word-splitting, you are better served storing the wanted environment variable in an indexed array, e.g.

```
services=( $(compgen -A variable | grep 'service' | grep -v 'services') )
```

(the `grep -v 'services'` in necessary to remove `services` from the list as it is declared before the call to `compgen`)

Now you can simply loop over your array making use of *indirection* and a counter variable to produce the `serverX=val` output you want, e.g.

```
declare -i n=1
for i in ${services[@]}; do
    printf "%s=%s\n" "server$((n++))" "${!i}"
done
```

Putting it altogether in a short example, you could do something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

service1=1
service2=a
service3=dd

## fill services with all variable containing "service", excluding "services"
services=( $(compgen -A variable | grep 'service' | grep -v 'services') )

declare -i n=1
for i in ${services[@]}; do
    printf "%s=%s\n" "server$((n++))" "${!i}"  ## use indirection to get value of i
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash compgen_tst.sh
server1=1
server2=a
server3=dd
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: You can loop directly over `"${!service@}"`. There would be no need for either `grep` :) and the `-i` flag can only create confusion in my opinion while the benefits are rather small.

Comment: That's a good point, I was a bit leery of indirection like `${!services[@]}'. You would still need a loop variable (or old `$1` and `shift`) to hold the values, but I can see how that might be cleaner.